# Interpolate and save a vector function

Tags: interpolation, save

i have a vector function as:

$f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$

for example:

```
SomeComplicatedInterpolationFunction=Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2}, {i, 1, 5}]];
f[x]:={Cos[x],Sin[x],Tan[x],Cot[x],SomeComplicatedInterpolationFunction[x]};
```

Now I would like to save the function f as a file so i can recall this later in a new mathematica cernel. I tried:

```
f>>"f.m";
```

but it didnt work, this gives just the symbolic expression of f. Then I tried:

```
f2=FunctionInterpolation[f[x],{x,0,1}];
f2>> "f2.m";
```

But this only stores the first entry of f.

**Whats the correct way to store a vector valued function without storing each component?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save):

```
f[x] := {Cos[x],Sin[x],Tan[x],Cot[x],SomeComplicatedInterpolationFunction[x]};
Save["f.m", f]
```

Let's check if it worked:

```
Clear[f];
<<f`

??f
```

> Global`f
>
> f[x]:={Cos[x],Sin[x],Tan[x],Cot[x],SomeComplicatedInterpolationFunction[x]}

Comment: wow that was easy, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_]:={Cos[x],Sin[x],Tan[x],Cot[x],SomeComplicatedInterpolationFunction[x]};

Save[f.m,f]
```

Comment: sorry if i my question was ambiguous. I want to store the function as a file on the hard disk of my computer not in the actual cernel. I want to recall the function in a new cernel with: f=<<"f.m". For a scalar valued function this works fine but the question is how to proceed with a vector valued function